# Change Base 1 Array to Base 0 Array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, excel, import-from-excel

I'm retrieving data from Excel and would like to keep my arrays 0 based but Excel returns 1 base. Is there a fairly simple way to return change the array from 1 to 0 base? Or do I just need to create a loop?

Here's an example code right here:

```
dim oData(,) as object
dim rng as range
dim wks as worksheet = xlApp.Activeworkbook.sheets(Sheet1)

rng=wks.Range("A1:B2")

oData=rng.Value2
```

Comment: Yes - loop. I'm not sure it's a good practice though - anyone familiar with how VBA works will know that the variant array from Range().Value is 1-based: if you change it to 0-based it may cause more problems than it solves,  particularly if soemone else ends up maintaining your code.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure how it was done in VB.NET, I'm using a library that I made from Excel 2003 execution file and thought it might be different because of that. I know Excel-DNA returns a zero based array, so I guess that is why I assumed it was standard to be 0-based in .NET. I guess I'll stick with 1-based array. If you put your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct, unless someone else comes by with a better answer between now and then.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I just noticed you were talking about VBA. So I guess you didn't answer my question for .NET. Well, maybe someone else will give it a shot!

Comment: I was mostly talking about changing the "native" behavior of Excel-derived objects.  However, there are some suggestions in a previously-asked version of your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497766/rebase-a-1-based-array-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A loop is the simplest option.

```
Dim target as string(0 to oData.Length - 1)

For index = 1 to oData.Length 
   target(index - 1) = oData(index)
Next
```

Thats from memory and not tested but it's obvious enough.